# Navigating between views in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flexbuilder

I am trying to develop a mobile application using flex. Whenever I use 'navigator.popView()' to go back to the last view that was shown, it loads a new view on to the screen, instead of using the old one itself.
On the first screen, I have a TextInput into which I enter some text, when I push next and then push back the TextInput is empty. I want to retain the text in the TextInput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is advisable not to keep views in memory by default, so discarding old views and creating new ones is really the desired behavior.  You should bind the content of your TextInput to a variable and store and retrieve only its text value.

Comment: Ok. But then is it possible to override this behavior, so that it will keep the view in memory.

Comment: Why?  Just bind the input value!